# Codeigniter view shows 0 record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, foreach

i've insert 5 rows into `ms_kategori_material` table, and made some model here

```
function read()
{   
    $query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material');

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {            
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $value) {
            echo $value['Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa'];
            echo $value['Nama_Material_Jasa'];
        }
        return $value;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and controllers

```
function index()
{
      $data['kirim'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->read();
      echo $data; //returns KKMJ001batuKKMJ002batuKKMJ003batuKKMJ004batuKKMJ005batuArray
      $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial',$data);

}
```

and the views

```
<?php  
                if ( !empty($kirim) ) {  
                 $no = 1;   
                 foreach ($kirim as $row) { ?>  
                 <tr id="row">  
                  <td id="no"><?php echo $no;?></td>  
                  <td id="judul"><?php echo $row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa;?></td>  
                  <td id="kategori"><?php echo $row->Nama_Material_Jasa;?></td>  
                    </tr>  ?>
                    <?php  
                     $no++;  
                    }  
                   } else { ?>  
                                <tr id="row">  
                                <td colspan="6" align="center">Data tidak ditemukan</td>  
                               //the screen shows 'data tidak ditemukan' </tr>  
                            <?php  
                   }  
                   ?>
```

this is so confusing, since i can see the data in the controller, then pass them into the views, views said no data received

Comment: Rather than if(! empty) try if(isset($kirim))

Comment: @rickcalder it returns error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Undefined variable: kirim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `model`

```
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{            
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $value) {
        echo $value['Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa'];
        echo $value['Nama_Material_Jasa'];
    }
    return $value;
}
```

it's wrong, it should be

```
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{            
    return $query->result();
}
```

and in your `controller` you should have

```
function index()
{
  $this->load->model('m_kategorimaterial'); // load it if it's not autoloaded
  $data['kirim'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->read();
  $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial',$data);
}
```

Comment: here, you can download the fullcode here http://www.mediafire.com/?5bawsym990aae19 sorry, i can't find my room to discuss this thread

Comment: You are using `$this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial',$data);` but you have `vkategorimaterial.php` in the `view` folder, so it should be `$this->load->view('vkategorimaterial`

Comment: Also read [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter/) to manage your `views` in a more organized way.

Comment: In your `controller` your `index` function must contain `$data['kirim'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->read(); $this->load->view('vkategorimaterial',$data);`

Comment: no, `vkategorimaterial.php` located on folder `views/v/vkategorimaterial.php`

Answer (score 1):

Just reread your code. You're returning $value but never populating it. See below.

```
{   
    $query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material');

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {            
        $value = $query->result(); // or result_array() but you're using it as an object in the view not an array.
        return $value;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not returning the results in your model,

**replace**

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $value) 
{
 echo $value['Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa'];
 echo $value['Nama_Material_Jasa'];
}
```

**with**

```
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{            
  return $query->result();
}
```